# VSCode + neovim: how to jump half page up/down and center screen vertically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, neovim

In VSCode with the extension `vscode-neovim` installed:

- How to set up the keybindings so that, for example, **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>** moves the screen a half-page up, and then centers it vertically?
- Vice-versa for down and full-page up/down.

I tried this in my `keybindings.json`:

```
[
  // disable the actual ctrl-u
  {
    "key": "ctrl+u",
    "command": "-vscode-neovim.ctrl-u",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert'"
  },

  // send the ctrl-u + z. for centering
  {
    "key": "ctrl+u",
    "command": "vscode-neovim.send",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert'",
    "args":  "<C-u>z."
  },
]
```

But after these changes, half-page up and down commands now jump 100 lines (instead of 20 like before).

Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/1039

Answer (score 3):

## Workaround

I found a workaround for this problem, this involves setting the keymaps to execute both commands as a sequence:

1. Install the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).
2. Go to your Keyboard Shortcuts JSON.
3. Set new keybindings for `Ctrl+d` and `Ctrl+u` with the following:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
      {
        "command": "vscode-neovim.send",
        "args": "<C-d>"
      },
      {
        "command": "vscode-neovim.send",
        "args": "zz"
      }
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert'"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+u",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
    {
      "command": "vscode-neovim.send",
      "args": "<C-u>"
    },
    {
      "command": "vscode-neovim.send",
      "args": "zz"
    }
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert'"
}
```

Comment: For some reason this moved the screen but didn't center for me. I swapping out "<C-u>" and "<C-d>" for "10k" and "10j" in args and it did basically what op asked.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

workaround for centered scrolling

Disable default implementation:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+u",
    "command": "-vscode-neovim.ctrl-u",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal.u && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert' && editorLangId not in 'neovim.editorLangIdExclusions'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "-vscode-neovim.ctrl-d",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.ctrlKeysNormal.d && neovim.init && neovim.mode != 'insert' && editorLangId not in 'neovim.editorLangIdExclusions'"
  }
```

Using multicommand scroll and move the cursor to center:

settings.json

```json
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.pageUp",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "editorScroll", "args": {"to": "up", "by": "wrappedLine", "value": 32 }},
        { "command": "cursorMove", "args": { "to": "viewPortCenter" } }
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.pageDown",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "editorScroll", "args": {"to": "down", "by": "wrappedLine", "value": 32 }},
        { "command": "cursorMove", "args": { "to": "viewPortCenter" } }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

keybindings.json

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+u",
    "command": "multiCommand.pageUp",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "multiCommand.pageDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

You can also use `"args": {"by": "halfPage"}` but it seems buggy

Comment: wasn't able to get the desired behavior to work by sending keystrokes to the neovim plugin via multicommand like the other solutions on this page, but this one worked for me.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The problem seems to be related to the commented-out code from the [`vscode-scrolling.vim`](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/blob/v0.0.89/vim/vscode-scrolling.vim) file:

```
" Disabled due to scroll problems (the ext binds them directly)
" nnoremap <silent> <expr> <C-d> VSCodeExtensionCall('scroll', 'halfPage', 'down')
" xnoremap <silent> <expr> <C-d> VSCodeExtensionCall('scroll', 'halfPage', 'down')
" nnoremap <silent> <expr> <C-u> VSCodeExtensionCall('scroll', 'halfPage', 'up')
" xnoremap <silent> <expr> <C-u> VSCodeExtensionCall('scroll', 'halfPage', 'up')

[...] (same for full page and line)
```